# How to externalize d3.js transistion configuration

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to define a d3.js transition configuration (`delay`, `duration` and `ease`), and than use this configuration on multiple transitions. For example, I would like to have the code that works like this ([run it](https://jsfiddle.net/5khgmjeb/8/)):

```js
d3.selectAll(".apple")
  .transition()
    .delay(100)
    .duration(5000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .style("fill", "red");

d3.selectAll(".orange")
  .transition()
    .delay(2000)
    .attr("cx", "150")
  .transition()
    .delay(100)
    .duration(5000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .style("fill", "orange");
```

but without repeating the `.delay(100).duration(5000).ease(d3.easeLinear)` part multiple times. What is the most D3-idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_call , which behaves quite similarly to the selection call. It allows chaining a function execution upon the selection / transition.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Click me</div>
  <script>
function applyTransitionConfig(transition, config) {
    transition
        .delay(config.delay)
        .duration(config.duration)
        .ease(config.ease);
}

var transitionConfig = {
    delay: 300,
    duration: 100,
    ease: d3.easeLinear
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500)

var rect = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 30)
    .attr('height', 30)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('fill', '#f54')
    .on('click', function() {
        var x = Math.random() * 960;
        rect.transition()
            .call(applyTransitionConfig, transitionConfig)
            .attr('x', x);
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Unless I'm misunderstanding,*

If you are looking to "define a d3.js transition configuration (delay, duration and ease), and then use this configuration on multiple transitions". You can define a transition with ease, duration, and delay like so:

```
var t = d3.transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeBounce);
```

Then to use this transition we can use:

```
selection.transition(t)
  .attr("...",...) // property to transition.
```

Giving us:

```js
var t = d3.transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeBounce); 
  
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",50)
  .attr("cy",50)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
  
var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("width",50)
  .attr("height",50)
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
  
circle.transition(t)
  .attr("r", 40)
  .transition(t)
  .duration(5000) // modify pre-configured duration
  .attr("r","20")
  
rect.transition(t)
  .attr("fill","crimson")
  .transition(t)
  .attr("width",80)
  .transition(t)
  .attr("fill","yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

For this approach's idiomatic-ness, the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selection_transition) contains this example:

```
var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear);

d3.selectAll(".apple").transition(t)
    .style("fill", "red");

d3.selectAll(".orange").transition(t)
    .style("fill", "orange");
```

Comment: Could you provide a code that use this approach to achieve the same result as the code in the question? I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/e5347u91/), and failed (the second `.orange` transition doesn't use the externalized configuration `t`).

Comment: Ah, yes I see the issue, I'll update with something when I get the chance.

Comment: Haven't forgot, on vacation for a week and a half more though. A solution exists in my mind, need to test properly when I get home. Sorry for the delay.